# Was noted karnataka music scholar and composer Purandaradasa an avatara of Narada?

Tags: narada

according to

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purandara_Dasa#cite_note-7

> Purandara Dasa (IAST: Purandara dāsa)[2] (c. 1470 – c. 1565) was a Haridasa philosopher from present-day Karnataka, India. He was a follower of Madhvacharya's Dvaita philosophy. He was a composer, singer and one of the chief founding-proponents of Carnatic music (Karnataka classical music). In honor of his significant contributions to Carnatic music, he is widely referred to as the Pitamaha (lit. "father" or "grandfather") of Carnatic music.[3][4][5][6] **According to a legend, he is considered as an incarnation of Saint Narada.**[7][8]